# nextScreen() Qml objects gets replaced in slot causes error. Is QueuedConnection solution?

Tags: qt, qml

Qt 5.8/5.9. I have a typical wizard like screens using QML each with back and next buttons. My own custom C++ widget object derived from QQuickWidget is the container.  When I get a nextbutton in one screen, I need to load another QML file. So my QML screen's object tree will to be replaced.

For example a next button click triggers a line like this:

```
      setSource(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/ProjSel.qml")));
```

Means the creator of the signal, a 'next' button object, itself gets replaced. In this scenario, I am getting crashes often. To fix I used QueuedConnection. Code is as follows. Hope I am **right**.

```
      QObject::connect(rootObject(),
                 SIGNAL(goNext()),
                 this,
                 SLOT(projectControlNext()),
                 Qt::QueuedConnection); // QML objects tree may be replaced.
                                        // The creator of signal can not be replaced in a slot.
                                        // So Qt::QueuedConnection is important for
                                        // an async execution of slots.
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use something like [`StackView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html) instead of replacing the QQuickWidget's source. Taking the example from the docs:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    StackView {
        id: stack
        initialItem: mainView
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Component {
        id: mainView

        Row {
            spacing: 10

            Button {
                text: "Push"
                onClicked: stack.push(mainView)
            }
            Button {
                text: "Pop"
                enabled: stack.depth > 1
                onClicked: stack.pop()

            }
            Text {
                text: stack.depth
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. My screens are not that heavy too. so performance may not be a hit. However QueuedConnection is also right in my context. right?

Comment: I would definitely not recommend destroying an entire QML component via an item in that component. The QueuedConnection workaround might work, but it's still a dodgy practice in the first place IMO. In a broader sense, UI navigation (pushing new screens) should be done in QML if you're using QML, not C++.

Comment: Oh is there a way to push new screens in qml without using C++ code?

Comment: @veenusAV, that's what the code above does. Just replace `stack.push(mainView)` with `stack.push(idOfYourScreenType)`.